# Is it possible to create a login for restricted visibility?

Tags: multisite, login, plugins

I use eStore (from Elegant Themes) with Woocommerce to build a webshop. I want to add a login page for wholesalers to login and have access to different products (2014 collection) and different price of the current collection. The 2nd wholesale webshop should not be visible unless the user is logged in.

Would Multisite be the solution? (But would I still have to connect iDeal to both sites?)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to [create a role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) for your wholesalers and then toggle price based on membership in that role, or limit access to certain "Pages" to members of that role. That is going to be much easier than multiple linked sites.

Your question is lacking detail and code (which might be closed source in this case anyway), so it is hard to be more specific but maybe that will get you started. Edit the question with more detail and I will revisit this.